# Prove that eigenvectors associated with same eigenvalue cannot be orthogonal for a symmetric matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

I understand the case where the eigenvalues are distinct.
How does it work for eigenvalues with multiplicity > 1?

Comment: It doesn't; consider the identity matrix.

Comment: I don't understand where are the downvotes are coming from. It is perfectly clear question with a perfectly clear answer, provided by Travis Wilse in the comment above this one.